# Webdriver C# Dropdown Control options not being selected

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have C# code to select an option from a dropdown control but the option is not selected.
The same code works as expected earlier in the script but its fails at this particular point - it fails to select the option then tries to move on as if it has succeeded in selecting the option.
Here is the code:

```
SelectElement endCategory = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$wnCore$ctlRiskAddEndorsements  $ddlEndorsementCategories")));
IWebElement endCategoryOption =   endCategory.Options.First();
  if (endCategoryOption.Text.Equals("Please select ..."))  
    endCategory.SelectByText("Endorsement");
```

I have tried both `Options.First();` and `Options.FirstOrDefault();`
I have also tried putting in a wait before just in case.

Comment: can you post the HTML code of the dropdown box you are trying to select.

Comment: Thanks for helping!  I actually just solved it by getting rid of the IWebElement and the "if" to make it simpler and it worked.

Comment: If you need to check the value then you could check the endCategory.SelectByValue();